# PHP Fetch Data from MySql Table like Twitter Trend

Tags: php, mysql, web-deployment

I have a mysql table as follows-

```
crId    ccId    ccatId  entryDate
458     186     12      2016-01-01
459     186     37      2016-01-01
460     186     117     2016-01-01
461     187     12      2016-01-04
462     187     117     2016-01-05
463     187     117     2016-01-07
464     187     12      2016-01-07
```

Now, I want to fetch data from this table like twitter trend part.

- Fetch all Data from table within last 1 week time
- Display top 5 entries from table according to descending order
- Count and display how many **ccatId** entry each. For example, in table, 117 has 3 entries, 12 has 3 entries etc.

How can I make this? I cannot find out the solution? Can anybody please help me?

Expected Outcomes-

```
12
3 times

117
3 times

12
2 times
```

Comment: The question comes..Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes... I tired with simply fetching data by 2 date range. But after than, cannot find out solution how to do so...

mysql_query("SELECT count(ccatId) FROM conferencerelation WHERE entryDate BETWEEN '$previous_week' AND '$nowTime' GROUP BY ccatId");

Comment: what is the issue with the logic you have used

Comment: Well, in my query, its simply fetching data from table during two date. After that I cannot find out any more solution how to get data like mentioned in question.

Comment: out will be '12'=>2 times and '177'=>2 time because fetch data from last 1 week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plese check below query :

```
SELECT ccatId, count( ccatId ) AS count FROM `tablename` WHERE `entryDate` > DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 1 WEEK )  GROUP BY ccatId ORDER BY count DESC
```

It return something like this ,

```
+--------+-------+
| ccatId |  count|
+--------+-------+
|   12   |    2  |
|  117   |    2  |
+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Display top 5 entries from table according to descending order use LIMIT like LIMIT 0,5

Comment: Thank you.. its displaying exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query :

```
SELECT ccatId, count(ccatId) AS rank FROM `table_name` GROUP By ccatId ORDER BY rank DESC;
```

It returns something like this,

```
+--------+-------+
| ccatId |  rank |
+--------+-------+
|   12   |    3  |
|  117   |    3  |
|   37   |    1  |
+--------+-------+
```

If you want entries from last week only then just put a WHERE clause.

Comment: Great.. its displaying data perfectly according to highest order of data. Now, if I want to display how many times each data has inserted, how to do so?

Comment: @tisuchi Show me the expected outcome as you did earlier.